# How does .NET framework low level APIs work?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, fcl

One of the questions that i always faced was the implementation of .NET Framework class libraries.

I know some of the methods original implementation:

For example :

```
MessageBox.Show("...");
```

As i know this method must have used P/Invoke to call Win32 API.

but something like this:

```
System.Convert.ToInt32(mystr);
```

I actually don't know how it works because conversion between int and string is not possible in pure C#.(Can you do exact same thing without using that method? Actually I don't know).

Finally if you know the answer please clarify these concepts for me speicially the 2nd example.

Comment: Source code of a big part of the NET.Framework is [available here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Comment: @Steve Thank you but i could see the source myself using reflector.But i don't understand it!

Comment: of course you can write a function to parse a string and return an int in pure C#

Comment: "Can you do exact same thing without using that method? Actually Nope)" - `int.Parse()`?

Comment: @Rhumborl But this is an alternative to that method. If i remove the power of .net framework from c#,can it do this purely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can you do exact same thing without using that method? Actually Nope.

You absolutely can. Here's a really inefficient way of doing it - which doesn't consider overflow, invalid input or negative numbers, but demonstrates the general principle.

```
int ParseStringToInt32(string text)
{
    int result = 0;
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        result = result * 10 + (c - '0');
    }
    return result;
}
```

Fundamentally there's nothing mystical about the process of parsing a string as an `Int32`. It's just a case of looking at each character, considering its numeric value, and doing some arithmetic.

Indeed, there are times when it's worth doing it manually - in Noda Time we have [our own numeric parsing code](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Text/ValueCursor.cs) to allow a limited number of characters to be parsed without having to take a substring.

Comment: Wow thank you.You turned on the lamp in my brain. What about communication directly with CLR? how it is possible?

Comment: @AmirrezaH: What do you mean by "communication directly with CLR"? Certain methods have a native implementationa which is CLR-specific, sure...

Comment: I mean that using specified CLR APIs. Low level types management. I'm sure that you have seen them somewhere.

Comment: something that bothers is the understanding the relation of .NET framework and C# because .NET framework does not act only as a API.It controls types,exceptions,memory management,etc.

Comment: @AmirrezaH: If you mean things like `GC.Collect`, that's likely to be a CLR-specific implementation.

Comment: .NET is not specific to C#. Same .NET is used by VB.NET, and you can use .NET Framework classes from PowerShell.

Comment: @John: All true, but I'm not sure how it relates to the question, which is about how the framework is implemented - and that *is* mostly on C# as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Jon, I was referring to the comment "something that bothers is the understanding the relation of .NET framework and C#"

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has made the BCL available online at: http://referencesource.microsoft.com

Calling `Convert.ToInt32(string)` will eventually call `int.Parse`, which in turn  will eventually call the actual routine on an internal `Number` class [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,a2e15b1a0fe0c25c):

One of the basic routines listed there is as follows:

```
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    private unsafe static Boolean NumberToInt32(ref NumberBuffer number, ref Int32 value) {

        Int32 i = number.scale;
        if (i > Int32Precision || i < number.precision) {
            return false;
        }
        char * p = number.digits;
        Contract.Assert(p != null, "");
        Int32 n = 0;
        while (--i >= 0) {
            if ((UInt32)n > (0x7FFFFFFF / 10)) {
                return false;
            }
            n *= 10;
            if (*p != '\0') {
                n += (Int32)(*p++ - '0');
            }
        }
        if (number.sign) {
            n = -n;
            if (n > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (n < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        value = n;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:
it's not the Microsoft implementation, since it's not open source.
but it should give you an idea

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/MessageBox.cs

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of [MessageBox.Show is here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/MessageBox.cs,d30dae02a986885a).

Implementation of [Convert.ToString is here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,069d595792a157df).